# How to compare Date + Time with current date and time?

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker

I have user selected date and time in string

> 2016-11-05 09:30 AM

I want to compare this date time with currect date time.

I used .compareTo() method along with System.getTimeInMilliseconds() but it is not working if i use current year.

I have used following code but it goes in else block if user selects date with current year.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new     SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd K:mm",Local.getDefault());
Date date = sdf.parse("2016-09-07 04:11 am");
    if(date.compareTo(System.currentTimeInMillis) > 0){
Log.d("date","Date in future");
}
else
{
    Log.d("date","Date in past");
}
```

Comment: "it is not working" means what exactly?

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code you are using for us to better help you

Comment: Sorry guys i have posted this question from my mobile, i have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DateComparedateTime(String date1)
{
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm aa").format(date1).compareTo(new Date()))
 }
```

Comment: It is not working, it shows an error on .compareTo(new Date()) "Found Date instead of Strimg"